# Zsh completion, enabling shift-tab

Tags: zsh, configuration, autocomplete

When zsh shows you a menu of possible completions, I'd like it to let me use `shift-tab` to access previous completion entries--is there an option that controls what key is used to access previous completion entries?

And if so, what would I need to add to my `~/.zshrc`  file in order to set it up.

If it makes any difference, I currently can navigate through a completion-menu using the arrow-keys, but I dislike doing this since the arrow-keys feel out of place and awkward to use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you want to bind the editor command `reverse-menu-complete` to the `menuselect` keymap.

```
bindkey -M menuselect '^[[Z' reverse-menu-complete
```

I am not sure how portable the escape sequence `^[[Z` is, so you may want to check terminfo(5) to see if there is a way of using the `$terminfo` array to correctly bind it.

Note that the `menuselect` keymap is available after you load the `zsh/complist` module. If you've configured the completion system with `compinstall`, that module is generally automatically loaded the first time you complete something. To be able to add that binding to your `~/.zshrc`, you need to load the module manually there first with:

```
zmodload zsh/complist
```

Comment: `^[[Z` is `shift-tab` on my computer too, so no worries about it not being portable; thank you.  :)

Comment: I get the following error when I invoke `zsh` after adding the `bindkey` line to my `~/.zshrc` file:  `~/.zshrc:bindkey:190: no such keymap \`menuselect'`

Comment: That would be `"${terminfo[kcbt]}"`.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer practically doesn't work for me. `zsh` crashes if I try to use menu completion (set `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select'`) with `zmodload zsh/complist` in `.zshrc`:

```
name clash when adding ZLE function `menu-select'
```

If you don't set `zstyle ':completion:* menu select` then it doesn't do anything (as the completion doesn't use the menu), or if you don't include the `zmodload...` then the setting doesn't work.

The correct, uncomplicated setting is:

```
bindkey '^[[Z' reverse-menu-complete
```

This works **both** if you enable the completion menu and if you 'inline' completion suggestions!